# How to auto fill the column of the active cell till the last row

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

Trying to execute below code:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Noting but F2





  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],4)"





' find last row with data in column "A"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



' copying the formula from "F2" all the way to the last cell

ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.EntireColumn & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

It gives an error saying type mismatch.

But when I try:

```
ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

It works properly, but I don't want F2:F there, as I don't know which column will be in future.

Comment: You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: `Range(ActiveCell.EntireColumn & lastRow)` makes no sense.

Comment: Hmm, what can we use instead of that or "F2:F" as the column number will be unknown at time of real execution. Only thing will be same i.e Header (Value in Row 1). @SJR

Comment: use `cells(2,activecell.column)` and `cells(lastrow,activecell.column)`. The active cell must be in the destination range.

Comment: That said, you can just apply the formula in one go, no need for autofill.

Comment: You've been advised against Selects before and given that link - if you're going to post here please listen to people's advice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you are not specifying a right range. A simple range can be, as you said, specified

1. Using the string format `Range("A1:B4")` where `A1` and `B4` are two opposite corners of the range.
2. Using the two corners as cells, e.g. `Range( Cells(1,1), Cells(4,2) )` where `Cells(1,1)` is `A1` and `Cells(4,2)` is `B4`

So you can write

```
ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(lastRow, ActiveCell.Column)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

To reach your goal you could also avoid using the AutoFill. FormulaR1C1 format allow you to write formula with 'relative' cell offsets/address. So after the AutoFill all the cells in the desiderd column will have the same FormulaR1C1.
Then you can avoid using the AutoFill and manually set the same FormulaR1C1 for the whole column.

So you can write a simpler code like that:

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(lastRow, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],4)"
```